# Sharepoint alert email were blocked by Sophos 10.0 - are they gone forever?

Tags: sharepoint, wss, sophos

We are running WSS 3.0 SP2 on Windows Server 2003 R2 x64. We had recently upgraded our Sophos Endpoint Protection from version 9.7 to 10.0. Immediately, our alerts stopped working (although it wasn't noticed immediately). When you tried to create a new alert on a library the page would just hang once you pressed Ok. No workflows that used email would complete. (See http://community.sophos.com/t5/Sophos-Endpoint-Security-and/sophos-10-and-sharepoint-2007/td-p/20119) None of the fixes mentioned in that post worked for us, so we uninstalled Sophos 10 and reinstalled 9.7 which immediately allowed *new* alerts to flow.

My question is... are all of the alerts that were blocked by Sophos gone forever, or are they queued somewhere that we just need to kick some process to send? I've tried restarting the server, restarting the timer service, [clearing the config cache](http://lovedjohnysmith.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/immediate-alerts-are-not-working-sharepoint-2007/)... I'm not sure where else to look. Any tips appreciated!

EDIT: Workflow emails apparently did queue and send. Alerts did not though.

Comment: Did you contact sophos support and ask them after explaining what happened?

Comment: If they are queued (or lost) and you find out from support it would be good to have it posted as an answer here for reference.

Comment: I emailed Sophos to let them know that there is an issue with WSS & Endpoint v10 (although they are probably already aware from the forum post). I doubt Sophos has the alerts anywhere, I'm hoping Sharepoint has them queued somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably so.  Sharepoint doesn't queue up mail, the sending application (sharepoint) would have to send it to a relay off of something that would queue it. The only way it would resend is if the actual mail creation job failed to start (and it sounds like that isn't the case)

Comment: Well, when it wasn't working I had run a packet capture and nothing was being sent across the wire. So either it was getting blocked at the network level or never even started. I'm thinking they're gone as well :(